# Firefox adding trailing slash and the URL breaks

Tags: magento2, url

I got a custom menu plugin in Magento2 as below.

```
class TopmenuPlugin {

    public function afterGetHtml(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $topmenu, $html) {

    $html = '';
    $html .= "<li class=\"level0 nav-1 level-top parent ui-menu-item\">";
    $html .= "<a href='\index.php' class='level-top ui-corner-all' aria-haspopup=\"true\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"menuitem\"><span class=\"ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e\"></span><span>" . __("Home") . "</span></a>";
    $html .= "</li>";
    ....
```

In Chrome and IE the URL is

```
http://website.com/index.php
```

In Firefox the URL is

```
http://website.com\/index.php
```

And in Firefox I am getting `Whoops, our bad...` error

Is there something I am missing here????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I change from

```
<a href='\index.php'
```

to

```
<a href='/index.php'
```

it works great.

Answer (score 0):

How is your base url set? Because if your base url is http://website.com\ by accident then u will have this problem. stores --> configuration -->  general --> web. It should be http://website.com/

Comment: The base URL is already as `http://website.com/`

Comment: Can u try clearing your cookie and cache following these steps :https://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/951951

Comment: Also clear the cache of the website and run php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I cleared everything in firefox.  Cleared the Magento cache and rebuilt the indexes...  fyi.. I installed firefox few minutes before just for testing this issue.

Comment: Can u post your php.ini settings? I know there is a settings that defines if u allow file links or not. It seems that this link has been marked as a file link for some reason and then it does that in firefox appearently. If thats not the case then i'm out of idea's xd wish u the best luck though

Comment: If that is the case then Chrome or IE should also have the same problem...  I got other URLS in the same Page which was working fine.  The problem is only via Magento Plugin (Top Menu)